# Conditionally disable a submit button based on the time of day

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am building a World Cup predictor game and I am having trouble with an element I have never had to use before. Basically I need a button to disable if the time passes a certain point - I don't want people to be able to submit/edit predictions after the match has based.

Can someone point me in the right direction. I have created a very basic form as you can see below. To be clear I need to know how to disable the button if the client time is lets say after 15:00 on 01/07/2018.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="engine.asp" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
<table width="50%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">Team Name:</td>
    <td width="50%"><label>
      <input type="text" name="TeamName" id="TeamName" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">Winner?:</td>
    <td width="50%"><label>
      <input type="text" name="WinningTeam" id="WinningTeam" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">Total Goals?:</td>
    <td width="50%"><label>
      <input type="text" name="TotalGoals" id="TotalGoals" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd appreciate any and all help you fine people could provide :)

Thanks in advance.

S.

Comment: I would start with a way of getting the current time in a format that works easy for you to read and work with. Moment.js may be worth looking into. After that it is just a matter of writing a conditional based on the current time.

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree with chevy's suggestion of Moment.js, only because any sort of front-end disabling will likely be very easy to bypass. If you're using asp.net (as you've tagged), I'd write your method on the server side. *This all in mind*, we're not going to write the code for you, especially without any indication that you've tried and/or researched it on your own. We're here to help you *debug your attempts*, not write them from scratch - however, without an attempt shown, we have nothing to debug :) Please edit your question!

Comment: Instead of disabling button , you can take current time when form is submit. You have time in asp.net contoller. Either you can procede  the request or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can disable the button on the client side.  I would also suggest having a server side button click event that does the same check in case someone tries to bypass the disabled button.

Client side check:
I would first give you btn an id:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="button" value="Submit" />
```

Attach a function to the window.onload global event handler:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var myInterval = setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
}
```

A simple function to compare dates, stop the interval, and disable the button:

```
function checkTime(){
    var now = new Date();
    var dateLimit = new Date("2018-01-07T15:00:00")
    if (now > dateLimit){
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

server side check:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime dateLimit = new Date(2018, 01, 07, 15, 0, 0);
    if(DateTime.Compare(now, dateLimit) < 0)
    {
        //process the event
    }
    else
    {
        //send error message to user
        return;
    }

}
```